# "rails s" not working on MacOS- "cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After my computer goes to sleep, when running "rails s" or "./bin/dev" (using esbuild for react with rails) I get this long list of errors:

```
<internal:/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)
        from <internal:/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from /Users/user/Desktop/InventoryVault/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in `require'
        from /Users/user/Desktop/InventoryVault/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.14.2-arm64-darwin/lib/nokogiri/extension.rb:31:in `rescue in <main>'
        from /Users/user/Desktop/InventoryVault/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.14.2-arm64-darwin/lib/nokogiri/extension.rb:4:in `<main>'
        from /Users/user/Desktop/InventoryVault/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.14.2-arm64-darwin/lib/nokogiri.rb:8:in `require_relative'
        from /Users/user/Desktop/InventoryVault/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.14.2-arm64-darwin/lib/nokogiri.rb:8:in `<main>'
        from <internal:/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from /Users/user/Desktop/InventoryVault/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from /Users/user/Desktop/InventoryVault/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/loofah-2.19.1/lib/loofah.rb:4:in `<main>'
        from <internal:/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from /Users/user/Desktop/InventoryVault/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from /Users/user/Desktop/InventoryVault/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.5.0/lib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `<main>'
        from <internal:/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from /Users/user/Desktop/InventoryVault/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from /Users/user/Desktop/InventoryVault/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.2/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:3:in `<main>'
        from <internal:/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from /Users/user/Desktop/InventoryVault/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from /Users/user/Desktop/InventoryVault/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.2/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:8:in `<main>'
        from <internal:/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from /Users/user/Desktop/InventoryVault/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from /Users/user/Desktop/InventoryVault/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.4.2/lib/sprockets/rails/context.rb:1:in `<main>'
        from <internal:/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from /Users/user/Desktop/InventoryVault/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from /Users/user/Desktop/InventoryVault/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.4.2/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:10:in `<main>'
        from <internal:/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from /Users/user/Desktop/InventoryVault/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from /Users/user/Desktop/InventoryVault/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.4.2/lib/sprockets/rails.rb:3:in `<main>'
        from <internal:/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from /Users/user/Desktop/InventoryVault/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/runtime.rb:73:in `rescue in block in require'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/runtime.rb:51:in `block in require'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `each'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler.rb:196:in `require'
        from /Users/user/Desktop/InventoryVault/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
        from <internal:/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
```

There are around 150 lines of similar messages that I had to remove for the sake of the spam filter

I've cleared tmp cache, reinstalled nokigiri, and added/removed sass but I'm not sure what else to try.

**Update:**

I'm able to temporarily fix the issue by deleting the entire vendor/bundle directory and then running "bundle install". Everything breaks again after my computer goes to sleep, but this works for the time being

Comment: You're going to have to do better than telling us it happens "randomly". Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You are the only person with access to debugging information necessary to understand and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Alright, so I'm quite new to this stuff so I'm trying to figure out how to reproduce this error, but I've narrowed it down to this: It happens on any rails build I make, and new rails build will run fine until I put my computer into sleep, then this error starts to occur.